# PHP bcrypt gives really short output for some reason

Tags: php, hash, bcrypt

https://alias.io/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/

I am following this tutorial to create a login system on my website but when I try to hash the password with bcrypt as shown in the tutorial the output is really short for some reason.

Example input password: gf45_gdf#4hg

Example salt: $2a$20$wEJ27V9qx.HWP68SNLcF7w==

Example output hash: $2l6f23nreXR6

I feel like that would be really easy to brute force, compared to some outputs online which are pretty long, here's the code:

```
$cost = 10;
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
$salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;
$hash = crypt($password, $salt);
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can increase the length of my hashes?

Comment: why all of that when you could use [password_hash()](http://php.net/password_hash) and let it do all the heavy lifting?

Comment: I can't use password_hash() because I am running my website in a free host that only lets me use PHP 5.2

Comment: You _might_ be able to use this backport: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat It depends on how your host's PHP package was built.

Comment: Do you feel trading security for free is good?

Comment: @zaph No, but I am a high school student and I don't have a valid money income. I would love to buy a virtual machine and experiment with node.js but I can't, so I have to use whats available to me.

Comment: @mkasberg I tried adding the library but it did not work.. I don't like free hosts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php
it will return a "string that is shorter than 13 characters and is guaranteed to differ from the salt" if it errors. So that could be what's going on?

Try checking if CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1 on your system.

Alternatively just use password_hash() as that should handle the salt generation for you.

Comment: I checked and CRYPT_BLOWFISH is actually 0, but I can't use password_hash() because my free host only allows me to use PHP 5.2.

Comment: It looks like you're using a Blowfish salt `$2a$...`. That won't work if `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` isn't supported.

Comment: Well, what can I do?

Comment: If blowfish isn't available you're probably going to have to use another algorithm. SHA512 looks like the next best. For that you'd structure your salts like "$6$rounds=5000$".salt_here with however many rounds you want. If that doesn't work either then you're probably not going to be able to get great security, try another server.